# How to install Windows server with UEFI?

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, windows-server-2012-r2, bootmgr

To install `SW_DVD9_Windows_Svr_Std_and_DataCtr_2012_R2_64Bit_English_-4_MLF_X19-82891` on to an RD230 [server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkServer#RD230) in `UEFI` mode `secure boot` must be enabled, correct?

The `ISO` was written to `USB` with `Rufus` with `UEFI` mode selected.

*While I didn't capture the note, `Rufus` seemed to, as I recall, indicate that `secure boot` should be **disabled**.  Surely `secure boot` should be **enabled** for `UEFI`.*

--

reference:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface

Comment: This subject seems to be well covered: [install windows server uefi](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=install+windows+server+uefi). There's no sense in rehashing the steps that are all across the web. You should probably state a problem you are having so someone can field an answer.

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 is based on Windows 8.1 not Windows 10

Comment: @Ramhound, why is it significant that Windows Server 2012 R2 is based on Windows 8.1 and not Windows 10?

Comment: Because you provided a link about Windows 10/Server 2016.  There are some significant differences between Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

Comment: I see, okay.  My fault then.

Comment: How about you just try it.  I may be wrong but i think if you get it wrong then you just get an error and it won't install?

Comment: Fair enough.  Another person tried many times in UEFI mode.  Right now it's installed in Legacy mode, so we might just leave it there.  However, with legacy mode, MBR has a hard drive size limitation.  So, yes, will likely try with UEFI.

Comment: You can’t use MBR and UEFI with any version of Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Surely secure boot should be enabled for UEFI

Rufus only asks you to **temporarily** disable Secure Boot, and the reason it needs to do that is because, if your ISO contains a file that is larger than 4GB, then you cannot use FAT32 to write it but have to use NTFS (as FAT32 cannot accommodate files that are larger than 4GB, a technical limitation of that file system). But this means that you also need an NTFS UEFI driver & bootloader to boot that drive in UEFI mode.

Rufus can and does install those files for you. However, because of Microsoft's *arbitrary* decisions (point 4 [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows_hardware_certification/2013/12/03/microsoft-uefi-ca-signing-policy-updates/)) with regards to what can and cannot be signed for Secure Boot, the files that Rufus uses, which are licensed under the GPLv3, cannot be signed for Secure Boot, which means that Secure Boot must be **TEMPORARILY** disabled for the first boot where the NTFS bootloader has to be used. But **of course** you can reenable it afterwards, and you should understand that, because Rufus is itself digitally signed and if you have validated the SHA-1 of the Windows ISO you used, **temporarily** disabling Secure Boot is not as great a security risk as people tend to believe (in other words it's not because it's called *"Secured Something"* that it should never be disabled, ever).

For more information on this, you can read [this entry](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Why_do_I_need_to_disable_Secure_Boot_to_use_UEFINTFS) from the Rufus FAQ.

But again, the message you have gotten for Rufus did mention very explicitly (I know, because I'm the one who wrote that message) that the disabling of Secure Boot was only to be **temporary**. Oh, and I also made sure that, besides that message, there was a direct link to the FAQ entry I pointed above, that user can consult if they need more info about why Rufus asks them to **temporarily** disable Secure Boot. So please try to also pay attention to what the application tells you, as it might answer your questions...

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but are there issues with getting a large RAID disk recognized by the install media?

Comment: Shouldn't be, if you have the relevant Windows drivers injected in your media (provided that Windows doesn't have them by default) or can provide them during the installation process.